# Why is notifyAll() not waking all of the threads in this example?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I'm trying to figure out how to use wait & notify, so I've written this small example with a few planes waiting for a runway to clear before they take off, the issue I'm having is that when a plane takes off, and calls notifyAll(), only one thread seems to be woken up, i.e. I expect all of the threads to report that they have been notified, but are still waiting. What actually happens is that only one thread is woken, and the rest do nothing. Why does it appear that only the one thread is woken, and how can I fix it?

```
class Plane extends Thread
{
    Runway runway;

    Plane(int id, Runway runway)
    {
        super(id + "");
        this.runway = runway;

    }

    public void run()
    {
        runway.taxi();
        runway.takeoff();
    }
}

class Runway
{
    boolean isFull;

    Runway()
    {
        isFull = false;;
    }

    public synchronized void taxi()
    {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " started to taxi");
        while(isFull)
        {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is queued");
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){}     
        }
        isFull = true;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " entering runway");
    }

    public synchronized void takeoff()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){}
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " took off");
        isFull = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runway runway = new Runway();
        new Plane(1, runway).start();
        new Plane(2, runway).start();
        new Plane(3, runway).start();
        new Plane(4, runway).start();
    }
}
```

Thanks for taking the time to help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have 4 Planes that are all `start()`-ed one after the other.

All 4 will attempt to call `taxi()` followed by `takeoff()`

The first one will call `taxi()`:

- acquire the lock,
- find `isFull` is `false`
- set `isFull` to `true`
- return, releasing the lock

Then one (or more) of the remaining threads may get to call `taxi()`.  If they do, they:

- acquire the lock
- find `isFull` is `false`
- call `wait()` which releases the lock

OR

- block while trying to acquire the lock

In the mean time, the thread that returned from `taxi()` will call `takeoff()`.  This will:

- acquire the lock
- sleep for 1 second,
- notify any threads that were waiting
- return, releasing the lock.

---

So how does this explain what you are seeing?

Suppose that when the first thread returned from `taxi()` it was immediately able to reacquire the lock and start the `takeoff()` call.  It would then call `sleep()` WHILE HOLDING THE LOCK.  This would prevent any other threads from starting their `taxi()` calls (if they hadn't already done so).  Then after the sleep, it would call `notifyAll()`.  But that would only notify the threads that were had gotten into the `taxi()` call and that had called `wait()`.  Any threads that were blocked while starting the `taxi()` call would never see the notifications.

(Notifications are never queued for threads that are not in `wait()` calls.)

Is this likely?  Well yes it is.

Starting a thread is a relatively expensive / time consuming process, and there is a good chance that the first thread started will get to do a lot of work before the next one gets started.  The chances are that it will get all the way to the `sleep` call before the second one tries to call `taxi()`.

The same pattern is likely to repeat for the remaining threads.  When each thread that gets into `taxi()` is likely to release and then reacquire it before another thread is scheduled.  (Thread scheduling is handled by the OS, and it is optimizing for efficiency rather than fairness.  If you want fair scheduling, you need to use a `Lock` object.)

---

> ... how can a fix it?

Change your code so that you don't `sleep` while holding the lock.  For example:

```
public void takeoff() {
    try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // squash ...
    }
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " took off");
    synchronize (this) {
        isFull = false;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because notifyAll() is not wakeAll(). All threads are notified, but only one gets hold of the key and is being run. All others get to waiting pull again.

Answer (score 1):

That's what it does.  It "notifies" all the waiting threads, but only one wakes and gets the CPU.  [`notify()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--) picks a waiting thread based on what the underlying thread implementation selects.  [`notifyAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notifyAll--) gives all the waiting threads an equal chance to compete.  But either way, only one thread takes the context.

Comment: Actually, the way the OP's code is written, the other threads are not waiting, so they never see a notification.  See my answer for a detailed analysis (and a fix).